# Webview loadUrl exceeds 2097152 characters

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem with my Android application.
I have a lot of GeoJson objects, and I load all of them with loadUrl.
However, when one GeoJson exceeds 2097152 characters, it will not be shown on the map.
Is there a way to pass the data to the webview, and not triggering the error?
I have not found any way to do this.

This is my code:

```
final WebView browser;
WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);

GeoClient geo = new GeoClient();
browser.setWebChromeClient(geo);        
String origin = "";
geo.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, this);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
              browser.loadUrl("javascript:AndroidFunction(" + messagea + "," + messageb + "," + messagec + "," + messaged + "," + messagee + "," + messagef + "," + messageg + ")");
```

And here is the problem with the loadUrl.
Is there any way to handle this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your targetSdkVersion in manifest is 19+ ( base on chromium ).
So, you can use the evaluateJavascript() method instead of loadUrl.
loadUrl only work fine without above error in version 18-.
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html.

Gook luck.